# How can I run openvpn client as a daemon if my config requires password

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I want to run openvpn connection as a daemon but my sertificate requires password.

```
sudo openvpn --client --config 5vpn-vpner.ovpn
Fri Apr  3 12:12:18 2020 OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on May 14 2019
Fri Apr  3 12:12:18 2020 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018, LZO 2.08
Fri Apr  3 12:12:18 2020 WARNING: --ns-cert-type is DEPRECATED.  Use --remote-cert-tls instead.
Enter Private Key Password:
```

I know that password, but if i try to add --daemon flat the password does not requested

```
(base) ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/openvpn$ sudo openvpn --client --config 5vpn-vpner.ovpn --daemon
(base) ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/openvpn$
```

after it I can't ping remote server

Comment: Maybe ths is what you need?
https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO5292.html